# How to retrieve ordered objects through a ordered association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have following associations:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations,
    :class_name => 'CategoryAssociation'

  # Note: Same as :category_associations but gets records ordered by :position.
  has_many :positioned_category_associations,
    :class_name => 'CategoryAssociation',
    :order      => :position

  has_many :categories,
    :through    => :category_associations,
    :source     => :category

  # Note: Same as :categories but gets records ordered by :position.
  has_many :positioned_categories,
    :through    => :category_associations,
    :source     => :category,
    :order      => [:category_associations => :position]
end
```

With the above code I can call `@article.positioned_categories` and get categories properly ordered by position. However, *I would like to use the `:positioned_category_associations` in order to retrieve `:positioned_categories`* but if I state the following:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_many :positioned_categories,
    :through    => :positioned_category_associations,
    :source     => :category

  # instead of
  #
  # has_many :positioned_categories,
  #   :through    => :category_associations,
  #   :source     => :category,
  #   :order      => [:category_associations => :position]
end
```

it seems do not work as expected: I gets *not* ordered categories.

How to retrieve *ordered* categories through `:positioned_category_associations`? Is it possible?

---

*Bonus*: Since `:category_associations` and `:positioned_category_associations` have almost same statements (except for the `:order => :position`), is it possible to refactoring `:positioned_category_associations` statements so to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) the code?